# Easy way to access all of my asked questions

Tags: support, questions

Is there a simple fast way to see all my recent questions?

Comment: Faster than going to your profile and clicking the questions tab (ordering by newest)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two clicks: click on your avatar on the top bar to bring up your profile. You'll then see a 'question' tab heading: you can click on that.

You could also add the URL to your favourites in your browser. For me I'd add

```
http://stackoverflow.com/users/2380830/bathsheba?tab=questions
```

One click. What could be easier?

Comment: Use http://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=questions as link, so that each user can open it

Comment: @Jehof I didn't know about *current*, +1!

Answer (score 14):

1. Go to your profile
2. Select Questions
3. Sort based on newest

> [image: Newest Question]

Comment: I want to upvote, but those freehand circles are the wrong color!

Comment: @JDB: changed color to red :)

Comment: Much better. I'll upvote too. Will help towards my acquiring the sportsmanship badge on Meta.

Comment: It's still a weird red...

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Changed that too. :)

Comment: It's still not what I want. Can you make it **pop** more? Give it some *buzz*!

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: There is no option available for doing that also I don't know to write user-scripts or not that much familiar with web technologies, otherwise I will try that too :) (just joking :) )

Answer (score 7):

You can take an advantage of *Advance search tips*...

type `user:me is:question` in search section.. and you get all question you asked... open the newest tab in there...

Comment: +1 The benefit here is that you can add other search terms, which beats paging through a long list.